# WCF Error - An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail

Tags: wcf, custom-binding

I have the below given setting in my web.config of my WCF service, this was working fine till today and suddenly started giving the error "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail." I have verified the time in my server and client it's same.
Any thoughts?

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="stsBinding">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="false"
          keyEntropyMode="ServerEntropy" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
          requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
      </security>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="66665536"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>

  <wsFederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="serviceFederation">

      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxDepth="2147483647"
               maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>

      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <!-- Ping token type MUST be SAML 1.1, do not change -->
        <message issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1"
            negotiateServiceCredential="false">
          <!-- TODO: You must put the proper issuer URN of the Ping STS; normally this would be the Ping base URL -->
          <issuer address="https://my-sso-server.com"
              binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="stsBinding" />
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Is there any windows patch that has been installed, sometimes this tightens security and stops things working.
- Is there a password that has expired, often the cause when things stop working.